# using buffering in Android MediaPlayer for playing mp3

Tags: android, stream, buffering

I have an url to mp3 file in the internet and want to play it in my app. Now i'm doing it as follows:

```
private void processPlayRequest(String url) {
    if (mPlayer != null) {
        mPlayer.stop();
        mPlayer.reset();
        mPlayer.release();
    }

    tryToGetAudioFocus();
    if (mAudioFocus == AudioFocus.Focused) {
        mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse(url));
        mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        mPlayer.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);

        mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
    }
}
```

It works, but it seems without buffering, i.e. playback begins only after entire mp3 file has been dowloaded. I want to start playback when it becomes possible for faster performance. So i need to use buffering. Is it possible to achieve?

Comment: it should play a part of a file by default, there is no need to add anything else

Comment: but it doesn't. I tried to add OnBufferingUpdateListener to my player, but it fires only once at 100%

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a [MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener.html), and call [MediaPlayer.prepareAsync()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#prepareAsync()), then call start() from the onPrepared() callback.

You're calling start, reset, release in an incorrect fashion.  Why bother starting, if you're going to immediately reset and release?

There's some pretty decent documentation around how to use the class in the developer [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html).

Comment: It's not a point. Sure it was a typo, i called mPlayer.stop() instead of mPlayer.start() before releasing player.

Comment: Btw while using MediaPlayer.create() it doesn't need to call prepare() or prepareAsync(), it is called inside create() method